# Rack topology in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, rack, topology

I was googling about rack topology and found this question...may be it's hadoop certification question:

Your cluster has slave nodes in three different racks, and you have written a rack topology script identifying each machine as being in rack1, rack2, or rack3. A client machine outside of the cluster writes a small (one-block) file to HDFS. The first replica of the block is written to a node on rack2. How is block placement determined for the other two replicas?

answer on some of the sites is Either both will be written to nodes on rack1, or both will be written to nodes on rack3.

Why not write the next block on rack2 itself and the remaining block on either rack1 or rack3?

Answer (score 0):

**If the Client is outside the rack, the first replication it writes is considered as the Local Node.**

From the documentation, Hadoop places replicas in 3 different Data Nodes:

**Local Data Node**: The Data Node where the client initiates a write (for e.g. using hadoop fs -cp command). The first replica is placed here. If the client is writing the data from outside the cluster, then this node is chosen at random. It is the node on which the first replica gets written.

**Off-rack Data Node**: The Data Node, which is present on another rack. The second replica is placed here.

**On-Rack Data Node**: The Data Node which is physically present on the same rack as the first Data Node. Third replica is placed here

Hence in your case, as first replica is written in Rack 2, it will be the Local Data Node. Second replica in either of Rack 1/ Rack 3 [Off-Rack Data Node]. And third replica again in Rack 2 [On-Rack Data Node].